# Jersey-Webservice. Getting 404 Error

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jersey

I'm trying to develop a Java Webservice with Jersey but the tomcat server keeps returning the 404 Error.

Some details:

- tomcat 8
- the server works
- other Webservices are working
- i am not using maven (all .jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory)
- EDIT: this should be the url: http://localhost:8080/webservice/hi

The Class:

```
package service;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hi")
public class Service {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String hello(){
    return "hi";
}

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String sayHtmlHello() {
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
  }
}
```

The Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>FirstRestWebService</display-name>
<servlet>
    <display-name>Rest Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>service</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace in the console?

Comment: I checked the tomcat log files, but theres nothing like an exception or another error

Comment: How do you call the endpoint. The same path has 2 different accepted response types. Do you do something like
curl -H "Accept: text/plain" http://localhost:8080/hi" ?

Comment: i tried postman and it returns 404 in both cases

Answer (score 0):

I see two ambiguities in your code. Your REST methods do not have different paths (**@Path**). Another thing that I see is that your servlet mapping does not mention **webservice** at all. So, even with **disambiguity** implemented, you will still have to add **webservice** to your mapping so that it works as you expect.